# When creating a reusable component in React, how do I pass all other props to be accessible later when the component is being used?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, jsx

I'm creating some custom components for my application and they essentially have some base styling done to them for light/dark modes. My goal is to be able to use those components with all their props later when the custom component is being used to stay flexible. How do I achieve this?

For example if I style a custom input component and use it, I want to be able to tap into the `secureTextEntry` prop when needed. Here is an example of what I have right now for my `CustomText`. I want to be able to style this further when needed.

```
import { Text, useColorScheme } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

type CustomTextProps = {
  text: string;
};

const CustomText = ({ text }: CustomTextProps) => {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  return <Text style={{ color: isDarkMode ? '#fff' : '#000' }}>{text}</Text>;
};

export default CustomText;
```

Comment: Does this code shows what you need or what you have now?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Hey, this is what I have now but someone actually was able to provide me with an answer. I realize what I was doing wrong and how to approach it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-native` expose interfaces for each component.
so you need to extend your interface with TextProps:

```js
import { Text, TextProps } from 'react-native';

interface CustomTextProps extends TextProps {
  text: string;
};
```

By extending those interfaces (e.g. TextProps) in `CustomTextProps` we can have all text element props passed to this component.

Instead of having to declare each one we can just use a spread attribute `...rest`

```js
const CustomText = ({ text, ...rest }: CustomTextProps) => {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  return <Text style={{ color: isDarkMode ? '#fff' : '#000' }} {...rest}>{text}</Text>;
};

export default CustomText;
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context) which acts as a store for global state that you can access using `useContext` hook